# Comparison is always false due to limited range of data type

Tags: c++

if someone could help me to solve this warning would be grateful. 
Thanks

Error code:

```
file.cpp: In member function 'bool CHARACTER::IsEmptyItemGrid(TItemPos, BYTE, int) const':
file.cpp:640: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
file.cpp:666: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
```

[PASTEBIN SOURCE CODE](http://pastebin.com/iRyxbaav)

Beautiful in this community. I did not know of its existence.

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE showing this warning, expanding the typedefs used.

Comment: Where I wrong? you please check and the source on pastebin. I can not find the one causing the problem. Can someone explain to me exactly what to change and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your line 640 is:

```
if (p >= DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM)
```

You've defined `p` to be of type `BYTE`, which is presumably an `unsigned char`, which means the maximum possible value of `p` is 255. Apparently `DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM` is some number larger than 255, so it's impossible for `p >= DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM` to ever be true.

At least at first glance, it looks like line 666 is essentially identical to line 640.

Comment: Thanks Jerry Coffin.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you need to do to get rid of this warning? 

I'm kinda new to c ++.

Comment: No, I can't. You've posted a link to ~7500 lines of code, and that's thoroughly incomplete because it includes a dozen or more headers you haven't posted.

Comment: I understand, I'll check and files included. Thanks

Comment: Can you give me your contact somehow. Yahoo email, gmail mail or skype? Help me with a source, there are serious errors but I can pay you to help me have the address.

Comment: Sorry, but at least at first glance, this doesn't look like the sort of code that would justify your paying even close to my consulting rates.

Comment: @CosminIovan use `int` for general purpose integers, even if their value will be small in practice.